# How to decode an encoded string?

Tags: objective-c, decoding

While decoding,I am getting NSData bytes by decoding a string.I am converting NSData bytes as string:

```
-(void)decodeAction:(NSString*)str
{

 NSData *data=[NSData base64DataFromString:str];
 NSString *stt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data];
 printf("\n stt %s",[stt UTF8String]);

}
```

Then I am getting the following output:

> <4f7c204d 6c204d61 604d6164 61616461
>   6164616e 24616e20 4d6e204d 6e204d6f
>   604d6f68 616f6861 6f68616e 28616e>

Comment: Ya. Accept some answers or people will ignore your questions.

Comment: Looks like this function is part of the Cocoa XML-RPC Framework (http://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc/tree/2.2.1). Maybe try looking in the source code there to find a matching decode function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
NSString *stt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or something along those lines.